# Building a generic interactive map from coordinates on Android and iOS

Tags: android, ios, canvas, core-graphics

I am working on an app for Android and iOS that needs to display a generic map of the United States (not a Google map, just state borderlines, no more detail needed or wanted). Each state needs to be tappable/highlight-able and the map needs to be easy to resize across the different screen sizes available to Android/iOS.

I've found that my best bet for rendering the map on Android is to use Canvas and on iOS is to use CoreGraphics and CoreAnimations.

I've found state borderline coordinate data on a site called [Global Administrative Areas](http://www.gadm.org/country) . The sites offer files that can be edited with Gqis.

This brings me to my questions:

Can you use Gqis to produce code that is usable by Canvas on Android and CoreGraphics on iOS?

Does anyone have a better idea on how to approach rendering the interactive generic map?

(edit) Am I on the right track with Canvas and CoreGraphics?

Comment: i don't think qgis will produce any code for you. You need a rendering engine that can translate your geo-data to some graphical form like polylines, polygon etc. Otherwise you have to do every thing by yourself and for that you can use canvas for android or may try surfaceview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing more research, I've found that Gqis, or Qgis as it's called now, does not provide an SDK to interact with geopackage data. I've found two solutions:

1. a paid solution - use ArcGIS's Spatial Database, Android SDK, and iOS SDK to handle the data from the geopackage.
2. a free solution - use Qgis to create a Spatial Database that can then be used with the free GeoPackage SDKs provided by the National Geospatial-Intelligence Agency ([Android SDK](http://ngageoint.github.io/geopackage-android/)) ([iOS SDK](http://ngageoint.github.io/geopackage-ios/)) to handle the data from the geopackage.

Lastly, Canvas and CoreGraphics seem to be a good way to handle the actual rendering of the map.